# Community promotion ad

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

**It is 2016 now and we can submit our site ad to this years community ad rotation on relevant graduated sites.  However, the image size and guidelines have changed, and the current image below is not suitable for this years ads.  We need to update it.**

As most of you might know, graduated SE sites have a feature called "Community ads" that consists of "community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar".

We, as a community, can propose such an ad to a graduated SE site whose users might be interested in ours, in order to gain some visibility over the network.

The way it works, one submit an ad on a meta post like [this one on Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6388/community-promotion-ads-2015/) and if the users of Physics up-vote it enough it will be displayed in the sidebar of their main site.

Here is a (non-exhaustive) list of links to the ad submission question on some sites that make sense for us to advertise on:

- [Physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7426/community-promotion-ads-2016),
- [Chemistry](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3079/community-promotion-ads-2016),
- [Biology](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3283/community-promotion-ads-2016),
- [GIS](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4133/community-promotion-ads-2016),
- [Aviation](https://aviation.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2871/community-promotion-ads-2016).
- [Academia](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2148/community-promotion-ads-2016).

[image: If you want down-to-earth answers to your questions]

<sub>(Picture was found on wiki commons, and the font is FreeSans, i. e. it is free-licensed)</sub>

If anyone as a better idea for an ad (these ads are reset every year so there is no time-constraint on this; plus we can actually propose a couple of them, the community on the target site will decide which one they prefer showing), or as any concern about posting such ads, or think about another (graduated-only) SE sites related to ours that I might have forgot, feel free to answer this post.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if retina.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of <s>40 KB</s> [150 KB](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271/237685)
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border surrounding it.

And most importantly: *we should only advertise on graduated SE site for which our site is directly relevant*.

Comment: Thanks for this!  We could also consider Space Exploration and perhaps Academia.

Comment: Space Exploration is only in Beta unfortunately so I can't but indeed I'll put it on Academia as well. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: [And here it is](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/a/1761/9664).

Comment: Ah right, I forgot about the beta aspect.

Comment: FYI Last year (2015), our ad was "clicked on" 612 times on Physics.SE, 351 times on Chemistry.SE and 516 times on GIS.SE.

Answer (score 9):

So, just so we have a fall-back option in case nobody has the time to create a proper ad, here's a very similar ad to last year's, with the proper, new specs:

[image: Earth Science on Stack Exchange]

I managed to make it a 33 kB file by saving it as a gif.
As for last year, the font is FreeSans and the [picture](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Asia_Globe_NASA.jpg) is from NASA, hence public domain.

Last year, at least one community on which i tried to have the ad placed refused it for aesthetic reasons, so if anyone can come up with something more "aesthetically pleasing" than this, that would be great.

**Edit**: Since I already got a complaint about the quality of the chosen picture, here is an alternative:

[image]

Comment: The ad can now be 150 KB, see [this answer by Grace Note](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/273271/237685).

Answer (score 5):

Here's my attempt at an ad image (i hate raster graphics!).  I will be posting this one to newly-semi-graduated aviation stack exchange, which gets a some weather/meteorology questions that could be better served here.  I chose a radar storm image since that will be recognizable easily to pilots.  I may remove the wind vectors when I have a chance, but have not decided.

[image]

Comment: I just have seen the ad on another site and on mouse over it showed "Tagline to show on mouseover". You might want to replace that with some actual text.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann fixed.  Thanks.